# How to refresh filter search WHEN the "clear button" at the edge of a text <input> is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, filter

I have filter for my list `<ul>` here is my html for the `input` where I have my filter.

```
<h1>Image Gallery</h1>
 <div class="searchbox">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search"  class="search" onkeyup="search()" id="myInput" >
</div>
```

my js

```
function search() {
 
  var filter =  $('input').val().toUpperCase().split(' ');
  var li = $('li');
  var a = $('a');

  for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      a = li[i];
      var text = a.innerHTML.toUpperCase();    
      for(var f = 0; f < filter.length; f++) {
            if (text.indexOf(filter[f]) > -1 ) {    
              li[i].style.display = '';
              //break; // don't need further matches
            } 
            else {
                  li[i].style.display = 'none';            
            }  
      }
   }
}
```

The thing that I want to is when I hit the `x` from the input and clear out letters and reload info, but doesn't reload the assets, you have to press `BACKSPACE` for this to happen. an example of this is [here](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp)

you can write anything and the filter works but then click on the X inside the input only clears the letters, then you hit `BACKSPACE` and you reset the info.

so how can you do this with only th `X` from the input, only one click and:

1. clear the letters
2. but also reset the info, like if you were pressing the `BACKSPACE`

Comment: i fail to understand what is `x`, am i missing something here?

Comment: it mean the little symbol on the right side when you hover over the input bar in the website, like the one you see in your browser the x for closing the browser, but instead in the input bar. @iceman

Comment: @Iceman The ::-ms-clear CSS pseudo-element represents a button (the "clear button") at the edge of a text <input> which clears away the current value of the <input> element. This button and pseudo-element are non-standard, supported only in Internet Explorer 10 and 11 and Edge 12+, hence the vendor prefix (`-ms` for Microsoft). The clear button is only shown on focused, non-empty text <input> elements.

Comment: I got it now!. anyways happy to know ur issue is solved!! cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to add an event listener to the clear button ('x') inside of your input field which will run your search function (or alternatively a clear function which you create which refreshes your data).

At the moment, backspace works because the `onkeyup="search()"` event triggers a function call that updates your data. The simplest solution would be to create a click event for the input's 'X' that calls the same function, ideally setting the input's value to an empty string. As I mentioned you could alternatively create a 'clearSearch' function and use that as the callback function to the click event which would specifically clear the previous results and set the value of the input field to an empty string.

Edit - Add example of event listener to invoke search method:

- As I mentioned above, it sounds like you have some code which generates a clear button (the 'x' you are referring to) inside of your input. I'm not sure what that is, so in my example code below I have simulated that behavior with a button (id="clearButton").

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" onkeyup="search()" class="search" id="myInput" />
<!-- Added this button because I'm not sure how you are generating the 'x' -->
<input type="button" click="clear()" id="clearButton" value="X" />

<script type="text/javascript">
// Use an event listener to assign the 'clear' function to the click event on the button
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("clearButton").addEventListener("click",clear);
}

  function search() {
    var filter =  $('input').val().toUpperCase().split(' ');
    var li = $('li');
    var a = $('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i];
        var text = a.innerHTML.toUpperCase();
        for(var f = 0; f < filter.length; f++) {
          if (text.indexOf(filter[f]) > -1 ) {    
            li[i].style.display = '';
            //break; // don't need further matches
          } else {
            li[i].style.display = 'none';            
          }
      }
    }
  }

  function clear() {
    // Select the 'myInput' search box, and set it's value to an empty String
    document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";
    // Call seach, which should reset the result list
    search();
  }  

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I used vanilla JS for the code I've added, but it will work the same with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

He is using the basic w3s search box in a full screen js modal that`s why the X - close button.

The solution offered by user4184202 was very good may be click="clear()" should be onclick="clear()"   ?

If anyone needs to also remove highlighted text you can use:
document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";

**$('#myUL').removeHighlight();**

search()

and it now clears both the input box and older highlights

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Below one is worked for me, when we typing inside search input field onkeyup will be triggered and on click of 'x' icon inside search field will trigger onsearch event and onsearch event will be triggering onkeyup.

```
<input type="search" id="search-name" class="form-control display" placeholder="Search 
by Name" onkeyup="callSomeFunction()" onsearch="this.onkeyup();">


function callSomeFunction() {
    // can write your code here
}
```