# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null in .net on clear filter

Tags: tabulator

```
I'm using Tabulator to implement search

Here's my html -- no problems until I try to search, then, I receive the above-captioned error:


<div>
    <select id="filter-field">
        <option></option>

        <option value="custId">Customer ID</option>
        <option value="custType">Customer Type</option>
        <option value="custName">Customer Name</option>
        <option value="groupId">Group ID</option>

    </select>

    <select id="filter-type">
        <option value="=">=</option>
        <option value="<"><</option>
        <option value="<="><=</option>
        <option value=">">></option>
        <option value=">=">>=</option>
        <option value="!=">!=</option>
        <option value="like">like</option>
    </select>

    <input id="filter-value" type="text" placeholder="value to filter">
</div>

<div id="example-table"></div>
```

`````
   I'm receiving an error in the JavaScript:
            ````<script>



        var table;


        function handleCellUpdated(cell) {
            console.log(cell);
            console.log(cell.getRow());
            console.log(cell.getRow().getData());
            var record = cell.getRow().getData();

            $.ajax({
                url: "api/SalesTrackerCustomers/" + record.id,
                data: JSON.stringify(record),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                type: "PUT",
                success: function (response, textStatus, xhr) {
                    console.log("success")
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, error) {
                    console.log("error")
                }
            });

        }


        function initTable() {

            //Build Tabulator
            table = new Tabulator("#customers", {
                height: "90vh",
                placeholder: "Loading...",
                addRowPos: "bottom",
                columns: [
                    { title: "Customer ID", field: "custId", width: 150, editor: "input" },
                    { title: "Customer Type", field: "custType", width: 130, editor: "input" },
                    { title: "Customer Name", field: "customerName", editor: "input" },
                    { title: "Group ID", field: "groupId", editor: "number" }
                ],
                cellEdited: handleCellUpdated
            });

            loadCustomers();
        }



        function loadCustomers() {
            console.log("loading data");
            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/SalesTrackerCustomers",
                method: "GET"
            }).done(function (result) {

                table.setData(result);




            });
        }
        // javascript for add/delete
        //Add row on "Add Row" button click
        document.getElementById("add-row").addEventListener("click", function () {
            table.addRow({});
        });

        //Delete row on "Delete Row" button click
        document.getElementById("del-row").addEventListener("click", function () {
            table.deleteRow(1);
        });

        // javascript for search

        //Define variables for input elements
        var fieldEl = document.getElementById("filter-field");
        var typeEl = document.getElementById("filter-type");
        var valueEl = document.getElementById("filter-value");

        //Custom filter example
        function customFilter(data) {
            return data.car && data.rating < 3;
        }

        //Trigger setFilter function with correct parameters
        function updateFilter() {
            var filterVal = fieldEl.options[fieldEl.selectedIndex].value;
            var typeVal = typeEl.options[typeEl.selectedIndex].value;

            var filter = filterVal == "function" ? customFilter : filterVal;

            if (filterVal == "function") {
                typeEl.disabled = true;
                valueEl.disabled = true;
            } else {
                typeEl.disabled = false;
                valueEl.disabled = false;
            }

            if (filterVal) {
                table.setFilter(filter, typeVal, valueEl.value);
            }
        }

        //Update filters on value change
        document.getElementById("filter-field").addEventListener("change", updateFilter);
        document.getElementById("filter-type").addEventListener("change", updateFilter);
        document.getElementById("filter-value").addEventListener("keyup", updateFilter);

        //Clear filters on "Clear Filters" button click
        document.getElementById("filter-clear").addEventListener("click", function () {
            fieldEl.value = "";
            typeEl.value = "=";
            valueEl.value = "";

            table.clearFilter();
        });
`````

Can anyone add insight on  this error? I have tried moving JavaScript around, and I think it may have to do with the placement of the JavaScript. It is displaying above captioned error on on //Clear filters on "Clear Filters" button click; it could also be on the load tabulator javascript function on table

Comment: Can you post your JavaScript?  You aren't calling addEventListener anywhere in the code above.  But, the error is basically saying that you are trying to add an event listener to a null value.  This may happen if your document.getElementById() returns null because the element is not found.

Comment: I added the entire JavaScript pertaining to Tabulator -- Thanks, Michele

Answer (score 2):

The error you are receiving is because you are trying to add an `eventListener` to a null value.  When using `document.getElementById('')`, if it does not find an element it returns null.  Because you are not checking that you found an element, your `.addEventListener` tries to attach to a null value, so the error is thrown.

Looking at your code, there are three areas that do not have an html element (from what is included in the question)
There is not a `filter-clear`, `add-row`, or `del-row` element in your HTML.  Based on you seeing the error above the `document.getElementById('filter-clear').addEventListener()`, it looks like your `filter-clear` element does not exist.

Here is an example that catches the error and appends the error to the body.
https://jsfiddle.net/nrayburn/58he2jr6/6/

Comment: do you mean something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886558/how-to-refresh-filter-search-when-the-clear-button-at-the-edge-of-a-text-inpu