# How to simulate keypress to clear input and refresh filter using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add a button that can clear the values of search input and also remove any filters (which is normally done by pressing a button such as backspace)..

I've tried calling the same function that does the filter but it didn't seem to work. I've been trying it with no luck until now...

Please see my code so far:

```js
// Links Filter
var input = document.getElementById("search-filter-cards");
input.addEventListener("input", searchFilterDivsMenu);
function searchFilterDivsMenu(e) {
    var filter = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
    var list = document.getElementById("links-list");
    var divs = list.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        var a = divs[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a) {
            if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                divs[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                divs[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}

// Clear input and filter
function clearSearchFilterInput() {
    document.getElementById('search-filter-cards').value = "";
    searchFilterDivsMenu();
}
```

```html
<div id="anchor-cards-list">
  <input id="search-filter-cards" type="text">
  <div id="links-list">

    <div class="card">
      <a href="#">example</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <a href="#">AAA</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <a href="#">BBB</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button onclick="clearSearchFilterInput();">Clear and Reset Search</button>
```

What's the proper way of actually clearing the filter? I've tried searching and searching but the only result online is this: [How to refresh filter search WHEN the "clear button" at the edge of a text <input> is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886558/how-to-refresh-filter-search-when-the-clear-button-at-the-edge-of-a-text-inpu)

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading undefined at

`var filter = e.target.value.toUpperCase();`

since you don't pass any event object to the function

`searchFilterDivsMenu();`

You could emulate the event like

`input.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));`

```js
// Links Filter
var input = document.getElementById("search-filter-cards");
input.addEventListener("input", searchFilterDivsMenu);
function searchFilterDivsMenu(e) {
    var filter = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
    var list = document.getElementById("links-list");
    var divs = list.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        var a = divs[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a) {
            if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                divs[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                divs[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}

// Clear input and filter
function clearSearchFilterInput() {
    document.getElementById('search-filter-cards').value = "";
    input.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));
}
```

```html
<div id="anchor-cards-list">
  <input id="search-filter-cards" type="text">
  <div id="links-list">

    <div class="card">
      <a href="#">example</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <a href="#">AAA</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <a href="#">BBB</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button onclick="clearSearchFilterInput();">Clear and Reset Search</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

change function `clearSearchFilterInput` like below is simplest way in this code i think

```
function clearSearchFilterInput() {
    document.getElementById('search-filter-cards').value = "";
    input.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));
}
```

```js
// Links Filter
var input = document.getElementById("search-filter-cards");
input.addEventListener("input", searchFilterDivsMenu);
function searchFilterDivsMenu(e) {
    var filter = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
    var list = document.getElementById("links-list");
    var divs = list.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        var a = divs[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a) {
            if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                divs[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                divs[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}

// Clear input and filter
function clearSearchFilterInput() {
    document.getElementById('search-filter-cards').value = "";
    input.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));
}
```

```html
<div id="anchor-cards-list">
  <input id="search-filter-cards" type="text">
  <div id="links-list">

    <div class="card">
      <a href="#">example</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <a href="#">AAA</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <a href="#">BBB</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button onclick="clearSearchFilterInput();">Clear and Reset Search</button>
```